# Как реализовать такое меню https://dashi-art.com/?

Tags: javascript, css

Как сделали меню вот тут: https://dashi-art.com/
Не могу понять. Может кто-то делал подобное?
По нажатию на меню (на всех устройствах, кроме мобильного телефона) текущий снимок экрана пользователя смещается вниз и открывает доступные пункты меню.
По наведению на пункт меню появляется снимок изображения наведенного пункта. После нажатия данная область увеличивается и становится рабочей.

Comment: Сейчас сделаю, ожидайте

Comment: @MoloF ждем ждем)

Comment: @thisman, Тоже заинтересовало?

Comment: @АлексейГринев это все делается через трансформацию, не шибко сложно) Просто хочется поглядеть на результат)

Comment: Проста бери этот код и переделай ничего сложного там нету. 
 https://codepen.io/andrejsharapov/pen/jJXEGq

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Спасибо большое. Попробую переделать...

Comment: *По наведению на пункт меню появляется снимок изображения наведенного пункта* - а у меня такого не происходит((

Answer (score 8):

Вроде похоже:

```js
function toggle() {
  document.querySelector('.body').classList.toggle('menu-visible');
  document.querySelector('button').classList.toggle('menu-visible');
}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   background: wheat;
}

.menu {
  height: 0;
}

.menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.body {
  transition: 1s;
  transform-origin: 50vw 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.menu-visible {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

section {
  height: 300px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50vw 100vh;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a>Home</a>
  <a>About</a>
  <a>Contact</a>
  <a>Questions</a>
</div>

<div class="body">
  <section style="background: steelblue"></section>
  <section style="background: teal"></section>
  <section style="background: steelblue"></section>
  <section style="background: teal"></section>
  <section style="background: steelblue"></section>
  <section style="background: teal"></section>
  <section style="background: steelblue"></section>
  <section style="background: teal"></section>
</div>

<button onclick=toggle() >Menu</button>
```

Comment: Мне надо чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в любом месте уменьшалась именно та часть, на которой пользователь нажал (у меня горизонтальный скролл на всем сайте)

Comment: @АлексейГринев я не особо понял =)

Comment: У меня на сайте горизонтальный скроллинг. Вот https://ederw.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Мне надо чтобы то место, на котором пользователь нажал на меню, уменьшался. А тут получается, что когда я нажимаю на кнопку, меня перекидывает в начало сайта

Comment: кнопка Меню будет position: fixed

Comment: сейчас поняли??

Comment: @АлексейГринев кажется да, и мне опять же кажется что это не должно выхывать проблем, нужно сделать пример =)

Comment: теперь я вас не понял)

Comment: я должкн показать, что получается?

Comment: @АлексейГринев ну да, что не получается, просто по описанию - не должно быть проблем

Comment: Ок, сейчас...........

Comment: @АлексейГринев только лучше не портить вопрос, задайте новый или сделайте на codepen

Comment: https://codepen.io/developclup/pen/JjjNgjd

Comment: @АлексейГринев https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/mddmNPM?editors=1010 там еще какая-то особенность с позиционированием текста, но в целом - надо скроллить не весь документ а только тот div который у меня `.body`

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но не могли бы вы сделать чтобы фон в меню был черным?

Comment: @АлексейГринев уже вечерком, я не у компа :)

Comment: После применения вашего способа у  меня появилась строка прокрутки. Если убрать запись ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}  Вот скриншот: https://prnt.sc/po3vvo

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100301/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and--).

Answer (score 6):

Извиняюсь что запоздал с ответом, решал технические вопросы, ваш пример полностью сделан на JS, довольно громоздко и не было необходимости так извращаться, постарался перенести некоторые моменты и сделать основной упор на появление. Получилось не идеально как в примере, но суть понятна. В частности решал проблему со скролом, в примере он фиксировано находился справа, я долго не мог понять каким образом он там примагничен, времени сидеть над этим было не так много, решил просто убрать его с помощью ::-webkit-scrollbar .

```js
$(document).on('click', '.nav-toggle', function() {
 $('#wrapper-toggle').toggleClass('focus');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #9e8974;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 100px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
header ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 1s;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
}
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0 !important;
}
.wrapper.focus {
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.wrapper .stub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper.focus .stub {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.wrapper nav {
  position: sticky;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 35px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper nav .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.wrapper nav .line:last-child {
  width: 50%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper nav:hover .line:last-child {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.wrapper.focus nav .line:last-child {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.wrapper section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.wrapper section:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Главная</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Автор</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Публикации</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Галерея</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Контакты</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper-toggle" class="wrapper">
 <div class="stub nav-toggle"></div>
 <nav class="nav-toggle">
  <div class="nav">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <div class="content">
  <section>
   <h1>First</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
   <h1>Second</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
   <h1>Third</h1>
  </section>
 </div>
</div>
```

Использовал JS для смены класса в объекте.

Более читабильный пример CSS (SASS) кода можно посмотреть здесь: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7qks4f2/2/)

Comment: Нет, всё таки не так получилось, автоматический подгон на JS в вашем примере очень кстати, нужно учитывать многие моменты. И очень непонятно почему на JsFiddle отображается нормально, но не здесь в выполнении кода.

Comment: Но в целом - очень даже похоже

Comment: @StrangerintheQ В целом может и не плохо, но мне не понравилось как я выполнил это :<

Comment: Пожалуйста, помогите натянуть ваш код на мой https://codepen.io/developclup/pen/JjjNgjd